# How to allow orders for out-of-stock products without enable Backorder in Admin?

Tags: magento-1.9, out-of-stock, backorder

We want to be able to take orders for products that are "out of stock" in Magento without enabled backorders in System > Config > Inventory.

How can custom code? Any other suggestions on that ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

If this is for specific products, you can actually allow backorders on a product level - in the inventory section of the product you can set "Backorders" to Allow Qty Below 0... this can also be done in bulk by using the action menu and selecting Update Attributes

[image]

Comment: Hi @aspiringprogrammer i know, but i want custom code to add product, not enable in admin